# Having issue with Intent Activities and Alert Dialogs

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I was wondering if someone could help me. It may be good to have a fresh pair of eyes to tell me what I am doing wrong because I just can't find it. It's probably something trivial, but I cannot see it. I basically have a button that when clicked brings up a custom dialog and asks the user to make a choice between an SD Card or Device memory. I feel I have everything right for the most part it's just giving me an error similar to: onClick error on line71..

Can anyone else see a problem..

```
    public class MediaActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

      AlertDialog.Builder builder;
      AlertDialog alertDialog;
      ImageButton sdImage;
      ImageButton deviceImage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button startApp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);



        startApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                Context mContext = MediaActivity.this;
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custlayout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

                TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
                //text.setText("Upload an Image or Video");

                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                builder.setView(layout);
                alertDialog = builder.create();

                sdImage= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sdImageButton);
                deviceImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.deviceImageButton);


                sdImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
                         // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                        Intent goToSD = new Intent(arg0.getContext(),
                            Sdcard.class);
                        startActivity(goToSD);

                    }
                });

                deviceImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

                // Showing Alert Message

                alertDialog.show();


            }
        });



    }  


}
```

Thanks a bunch I really appreciate this since I've been having trouble with this for awhile. It's probably some kind of a dumb mistake that I'm overlooking.

Thank you again!

UPDATE LOGCAT:

06-26 17:54:35.119: D/AndroidRuntime(24486): Shutting down VM
06-26 17:54:35.119: W/dalvikvm(24486): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-26 17:54:35.119: E/AndroidRuntime(24486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 17:54:35.119: E/AndroidRuntime(24486): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 17:54:35.119: E/AndroidRuntime(24486):    at my.edu.org.MediaActivity$1.onClick(MediaActivity.java:71)
06-26 17:54:35.119: E/AndroidRuntime(24486):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-26 17:54:35.119: E/AndroidRuntime(24486):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-26 17:54:35.119: E/AndroidRuntime(24486):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-26 17:54:35.119: E/AndroidRuntime(24486):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-26 17:54:35.119: E/AndroidRuntime(24486):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-26 17:54:35.119: E/AndroidRuntime(24486):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-26 17:54:35.119: E/AndroidRuntime(24486):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 17:54:35.119: E/AndroidRuntime(24486):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-26 17:54:35.119: E/AndroidRuntime(24486):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:850)
06-26 17:54:35.119: E/AndroidRuntime(24486):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
06-26 17:54:35.119: E/AndroidRuntime(24486):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
//////////////////////
implementation of onClick from droider's suggestions.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.sdImageButton: 
            Intent goToSD = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                    Sdcard.class);
            startActivity(goToSD);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sdclicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.deviceImageButton:
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Can you post your entire LogCat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited My Answer:

You need to initialize the sdImage and deviceImage ImageButtons in the OnCreate method.

Currently you are assigning an OnClickListener to two ImageButtons that are in a null state.

Change this:

```
      @Override 
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            { 
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
                setContentView(R.layout.main); 
                Button startApp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton

    ); 

to this:

@Override     
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)     
    {     
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.main);     
        Button startApp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        sdImage= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sdImageButton);      
        deviceImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.deviceImageButton);
```

Comment: I'll try that. Give me a minute or two and I'll respond back.

Comment: Oh and if you could, could you highlight which line is 71 for obvious reasons.

Comment: Sure. I should have done that earlier. Here is line 71:         sdImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

Comment: Also, I did try your suggestion. I implemented OnClickListener and the program didn't crash this time but it didn't register the clicks either. The implementation of onClick is updated above....

Comment: Found the problem. The sdImage has not been initialized yet when you try and assign the onClickListener. You need to initialize sdImage in the OnCreate method instead of the onClick method for the startButton.

Comment: Oh and you will have to do that for the deviceImage as well. Because the button hasn't been clicked yet those ImageButtons have not yet been initialized hence the nullpointer exception.

Comment: No, unfortunately it is declared at the class level above.

Comment: I see that however simply declaring ImageButton ib; will still leave it in a null state as you have not fully initialized it through ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton).

Comment: I took it out of the class level and put it under the onCreate as the following: ImageButton  deviceImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.deviceImageButton); For some reason still no luck. The program crashes for an odd reason.

Comment: Well, let me implement what you've wrote. Thanks again, you've been a GREAT help. Definitely kudos to you!

Comment: If that still doesn't work I'll try and write something that will emulate what you are trying.

Comment: Actually the program crashes. I don't know why though. Everything looks on the up and up, looks like standard normal stuff. Again, thank you ever so much. It's because of people like you StackOverflow is great.

Comment: No problem...hopefully you can get it to a fully working state.

Comment: For some reason I can't do ANYTHING with the ImageButtons. I think I'm going to totally re-write the application because that's pretty weird.

Comment: This might not be the problem but every once in a while I clean and refresh my project just in case Eclipse screws something up.